# Inner join in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, inner-join

I have been having a problem with the following query I constructed it keeps returning null, I am hoping that someone could just point me in the right direction.

The query is meant to return a list of branches that offer a particular service based on a service ID that is given. I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables being branches and services.

```
from b in database.branches
join bs in database.branch_services on b.branch_id equals bs.branch_id
where bs.service_id == objID
select b;
```

Comment: Are you making sure you provide valid serviceId, the query seems to look fine. Make sure you have data in the database

Comment: I do have data in the database.

Comment: By looking closer, the query is wrong, I will create an answer and provide the valid statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the valid query, adjust table names to match yours:

database.Services.Where(s => s.ServiceId == 3).First().Branches.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the lambda syntax?

Comment: No, could you please assist me in constructing it correctly?

Comment: Lamda expr is not an issue here, both lamda and Linq will work when valid statement provided